# vba read, transform and paste based on arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, transform

I have a main sheet with a data set of around 2800 entries and need to build new sheets with a subset of the main data based no some keys. I did it all with direct access through range and it was too slow. I try to rebuild the logic with arrays now.

My goal is to
(1) read a range into an variant main-array
(2) loop through this main-array
(3) build new arrays with subsets of the main-array based on criteria/keys
(4) Paste each new "subset"-arrays into new sheets

For one (1) I have

```
 Dim varray As Variant
    varray = Sheets("MAINSHEET").Range("B2:Q" & Sheets("MAINSHEET").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

For (2) & (3) I have something like this

```
For masterCounter = 1 To UBound(varray, 1)

  If InStr(1, currentUID, "KEY_XYZ", 1) Then
        subarray1(currentRow, 1) = varray(currentRow, 1)
        subarray1(currentRow, 2) = Trim(varray(currentRow, 2))
        subarray1(currentRow, 3) = varray(currentRow, 5)
 End If

      masterCounter = masterCounter + 1
Next
```

However, now I run into some type mismatch errors when filling the new subset array with values from the main array.

Any thoughts on how to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: How did you declare `subarray`? Second question: why did you put this into your loop: `masterCounter = masterCounter + 1`? It is not required, incrementation is executed by loop itself, you don't need to do it manually when using `For ... Loop`. Moreover, it can cause errors, because now `masterCounter` is incremented by 2 with every loop.

Comment: Hey I declared the subarray1 also as Variant. So from variant array to variant array. Datatype are text, dates, decimals. Sorry I needed to copy paste bits and pieced from my code. You can ignore the mastercounter, but thanks!

Comment: At what line did this error appear?

Comment: when I try to write the first entry into the variant array subarray1(currentRow, 1) = varray(currentRow, 1)

Comment: I ran into another issue. When I redim the subarray based on the masterarray each subarray has the number of rows of the masterarray. (Too big) Is there a way to only dim the datatypes but not the array size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redim `subarray1` before assigning values to it.

Insert this line before your `For ... Loop`:

```
    ReDim subarray1(LBound(varray) To UBound(varray), 1 To 3)
```

I assumed that `subarray1` should have 3 columns and as many rows as `varray`. If you need other size you need to change it accordingly.

Comment: Does that mean the structure of the arrays (master/target) needs to be the same? Because it's currently not...

Comment: @heyhey33 Yes, generally you can't assign anything to array until you declare its size.

Comment: Unfortunately now all the subarrays are the size of the masterarray due to redim. Is there a way to reduce the size (rows) of the subarrays to the actual numbers of rows (Content)?

Comment: @heyhey33 Yes, you can do it like that: `ReDim subarray1(LBound(varray) To rowsCounter, 1 To 3)` where `rowsCounter` is a variable storing the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

your code is to incomplete to help fully, (eg how do you declare and set currentRow) but here's something that might help.

Your array declarations need brackets...

```
    Dim varray() As Variant
```

Also, I would recommend being more verbose.

Yikes:

```
Sheets("MAINSHEET").Range("B2:Q" & Sheets("MAINSHEET").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

replace "Rows.Count" with ".Rows.Count"

ie

```
With Sheets("MAINSHEET")
    .Range("B2:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
end with 



Sub fred()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim varray() As Variant
    Dim subarray1() As Variant

    With Sheets("MAINSHEET")
        Set MyRange = .Range("B2:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

        Debug.Print MyRange.Address

        varray = MyRange

    End With

    For masterCounter = 1 To UBound(varray, 1)

        Debug.Print varray(currentRow, 1)

         If InStr(1, currentUID, "KEY_XYZ", 1) Then
               subarray1(currentRow, 1) = varray(currentRow, 1)
               subarray1(currentRow, 2) = Trim(varray(currentRow, 2))
               subarray1(currentRow, 3) = varray(currentRow, 5)
        End If

          masterCounter = masterCounter + 1
    Next


End Sub
```